# How to sum a field for just one entity?

Tags: mongodb

I have an entity "ledger" that I need to sum, but only for one user. Below is what I have, which is close to working. However, it is summing them for each user "user_id".  I have thousands of users so thousands of ledgers for each user_id.  I need to find the avg for one specific user.

Entities:

User "_id"
Ledger "user_id"

```
    db.ledgers.aggregate(
       [
         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: "$user_id",
               avgAmount: { $avg: "$amount_in_cents" }
             }
         }
       ]
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter on user_id and then perform the grouping

```
db.ledgers.aggregate(
   [
     {$match: {user_id: '<USER_ID>', amount_in_cents: {$gt: 2800}}},
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$user_id",
           avgAmount: { $avg: "$amount_in_cents" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Ok. That averaged them. Thx! How can I only consider ones where amount_in_cents is $gt (greater than) 2800?